# Text cleaning in R - Sentiment Analysis

Tags: r

if in a sentiment analysis with R, during the text cleaning I want to maintain for example the entire new york word instead of new and york separately how can I do it? because when I call the documentTermMatrix and I get a look at the freq of the words, appear to me new and york separately like single words.. thanks

Comment: NER (Named Entity Recognition) will help with that. In R `spacyr` can be used for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks...i will try

Comment: i can't understand how to do it..

Comment: NER will mark "New York" as a city, you can then make sure that city names (and other multi-word entities) are not split, for example by replacing the space with an underscore (e.g. New_York).

Comment: ok, but I didn't understand when and where applicable this NER in the text cleaning and with which function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include select 2-word phrases as tokens in tidytext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57303849/how-to-include-select-2-word-phrases-as-tokens-in-tidytext)

Comment: Take a look again at [ask]. Questions should have more specific detail than this